# How do I make a do block return early?

Tags: haskell, web-scraping, monads

I'm trying to scrape for a webpage using Haskell and compile the results into an object.

If, for whatever reason, I can't get all the items from the pages, I want to stop trying to process the page and return early.

For example:

```
scrapePage :: String -> IO ()
scrapePage url = do
  doc <- fromUrl url
  title <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "head.title" >>> getText
  when (isNothing title) (return ())
  date <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "span.dateTime" ! "data-utc"
  when (isNothing date) (return ())
  -- etc
  -- make page object and send it to db
  return ()
```

The problem is the `when` doesn't stop the do block or keep the other parts from being executed.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/breaking-from-loop.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`return` in haskell does not do the same thing as `return` in other languages.  Instead, what `return` does is to inject a value into a monad (in this case `IO`).  You have a couple of options

the most simple is to use if

```
scrapePage :: String -> IO ()
scrapePage url = do
  doc <- fromUrl url
  title <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "head.title" >>> getText
  if (isNothing title) then return () else do
   date <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "span.dateTime" ! "data-utc"
   if (isNothing date) then return () else do
     -- etc
     -- make page object and send it to db
     return ()
```

another option is to use `unless`

```
scrapePage url = do
  doc <- fromUrl url
  title <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "head.title" >>> getText
  unless (isNothing title) do
    date <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "span.dateTime" ! "data-utc"
    unless (isNothing date) do
      -- etc
      -- make page object and send it to db
      return ()
```

the general problem here is that the `IO` monad doesn't have control effects (except for exceptions).  On the other hand, you could use the maybe monad transformer

```
scrapePage url = liftM (maybe () id) . runMaybeT $ do
  doc <- liftIO $ fromUrl url
  title <- liftIO $ liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "head.title" >>> getText
  guard (isJust title)
  date <- liftIO $ liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "span.dateTime" ! "data-utc"
  guard (isJust date)
  -- etc
  -- make page object and send it to db
  return ()
```

if you really want to get full blown control effects you need to use `ContT`

```
scrapePage :: String -> IO ()
scrapePage url = runContT return $ do
  doc <- fromUrl url
  title <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "head.title" >>> getText
  when (isNothing title) $ callCC ($ ())
  date <- liftM headMay $ runX $ doc >>> css "span.dateTime" ! "data-utc"
  when (isNothing date) $ callCC ($ ())
  -- etc
  -- make page object and send it to db
  return ()
```

WARNING: none of the above code has been tested, or even type checked!

Comment: The second approach worked well for me. I think you nee do to

  `unless (condition) $ do`

for it to compile (notice the '$')

Answer (score 13):

Use a monad transformer!

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class -- from transformers package
import Control.Error.Util        -- from errors package

scrapePage :: String -> IO ()
scrapePage url = maybeT (return ()) return $ do
  doc <- lift $ fromUrl url
  title <- liftM headMay $ lift . runX $ doc >>> css "head.title" >>> getText
  guard . not $ isNothing title
  date <- liftM headMay $ lift . runX $ doc >>> css "span.dateTime" ! "data-utc"
  guard . not $ isNothing date
  -- etc
  -- make page object and send it to db
  return ()
```

For more flexibility in the return value when you early return, use [`throwError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#v%3athrowError)/[`eitherT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/either/3.4/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#v%3aeitherT)/[`EitherT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/either/3.4/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#t%3aEitherT) instead of [`mzero`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3amzero)/[`maybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/errors/1.4.1/doc/html/Control-Error-Util.html#v%3amaybeT)/[`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#t%3aMaybeT). (Although then you can't use [`guard`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3aguard).)

(Probably also use [`headZ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/errors/1.4.1/doc/html/Control-Error-Safe.html#v%3aheadZ) instead of `headMay` and ditch the explicit `guard`.)

Comment: What is `Control.Error.Util` needed for?

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with Haskell, but it seems quitte easy. Try `when (isNothing date) $ exit ()`. If this also isn't working, then make sure your statement is correct. Also see this website for more info: [Breaking From loop](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/breaking-from-loop.html).

Comment: Good link, but notice that `exit` is defined in the example and is not a builtin.  The solution in that post is the same as @dave4420's solution: a monad transformer.